# Why does Google File Stream disappear from Windows 8.1 after update

Tags: windows-8.1, google-drive-file-stream

I'm running **Windows 8.1 Pro**.  I've had **Google File Stream** stop three times now.  The first time I was completely puzzled, so I reinstalled it. The second time I used Windows search to find the app and started it manually.  I can't recall any precursor events for those instances.

Today, after I re-started Windows to finish an update, Google File Stream was not running. I searched for it and it does not show up.  I tried reinstalling it, and the installer objected that I had a newer version installed.  I found it in *Control Panel:Programs and Features*.  See the attached image.  Note the little bit of a folder at the bottom right that shows the status of my google drive as "not syncing".

I'm going to uninstall and re-install, but I would like to fix this problem.  Does anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks,
Ben[image: Screen shot showing Windows Search, Programs and Features, and the Google drive folder]

Answer (score 0):

This happens regularly with some products, after a major Windows update resets
some registry settings or software components.

I also have products that require re-installation after Windows Update.
There is no other solution, unfortunately.

Usually uninstallation is not required - you may just re-install or repair
the product, depending on whether a Repair option is available for
it in *Control Panel > Programs and Features*.

Comment: Thanks.  I just tried a "clean" restart (no updates) and Drive File Stream still did not start up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that *Control Panel:Programs and Features* lists *Google Drive File Stream*, but in the context of Windows search it is listed as *Drive File Stream*, and Windows search matches exactly from left to right.  I finally found it, and got it re-started

I'd still like to know why *Drive File Stream* **does not re-start** after a Windows re-start.

Comment: That's the old name, before rebranding.